# Need the power of index? Or just plain text searching?

Tags: django, search, indexing, search-engine, django-haystack

I'm currently working on a rather large events project, It's main feature is the ability to search through event models based on keywords etc.

I'm trying to weigh up the best option to take, whether to use something like [django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org) or just plain text searching through the models. It is only one model that will be searchable, however It could get pretty large.

If I was to go down the route of [django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org) what backend is the best to use? I'm running on a nginx with a debian OS. I have tried using whoosh, but for some reason the server runs into some errors whilst configuring it and I don't want to put the effort in to fix it to then find there was a better option all along.

Any resources that anyone could link also to help configuring haystack would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use solr  as backend whosh is ok but solr is

mature 
easy to install

if you have one model to index than you only need to

create your index model
index template
run rebuild index command

thats all :)
http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/tutorial.html#handling-data